# Customize the App Bar from the phone's opened apps menu with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making an app with Flutter and I want to change the text and the color of the bar that appears on the opened apps menu on the phone.
For example, in the linked image below, change the text from "Pokemon Go" to something else, and change the color from grey to blue.

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyrJhMbO_QCYgVxInVT1Ff1QuP_9aHAvClIg&usqp=CAU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this by wrapping your root Widget with `MaterialApp();` and specifying the title of the material app like:`MaterialApp(title: "Paco")` and specifing the primary color: `MaterialApp(title: "Paco",theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue),);`